# Using column names as range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that searches a column in a sheet using the col range as value. Instead of that, I need to use the col name (in that sheet) as he search criteria and perform the same function. How do I implement this?

```
Sub WBR()
Dim Count1Criteria As Variant
Dim Count3Criteria As Variant
Dim test As Variant
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

Filter1InSummary = Array(Array("AE4", "Latency", "O:O", "Pass"), _
                     Array("AE51", "TT", "G:G", "Yes"), _
                     Array("AE52", "TT", "G:G", "No"), _
                     Array("AE61", "Reactive", "R:R", "Item"))

Filter3InSummary = Array(Array("AE43", "TT", "I:I", "<>Duplicate TT", _
                                         "G:G", "<>Not Tested", _
                                         "U:U", "Item"))
For Each test In Filter3InSummary
With Worksheets(test(1))
    Range(test(0)) = wf.CountIfs(.Range(test(2)), test(3), _
                                 .Range(test(4)), test(5), _
                                 .Range(test(6)), test(7))
End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the column names would be in the first row of the worksheet, replace the 2, 4, 6 elements in the array with the column names.

```
Filter3InSummary = Array(Array("AE43", "TT", "CName1", "<>Duplicate TT", _
                                         "CName2", "<>Not Tested", _
                                         "CName3", "Item"))
```

Then replace the `.Range(test(2))` in the formula with this:

```
.rows(1).Find(test(2),lookat:xlWhole).EntireColumn
```

and do the same for 4 and 6.

Beware that the column names **must** appear in the designated row or it will fail.

Comment: I tried this but got syntax error : `Range(test(0)) = wf.CountIfs(.rows(1).Find(test(2),lookat:xlWhole).EntireColumn), test(3), _
                                 .rows(1).Find(test(2),lookat:xlWhole).EntireColumn), test(5), _
                                 .rows(1).Find(test(2),lookat:xlWhole).EntireColumn), test(7))`